# A normal subgroup so that any homomorphism into a $p$-group is trivial on it.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Problem**
>   Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and $p|n$. Show that there is a unique normal subgroup $N$ satisfying the following property:

1. $G/N$ is a $p$-group (I guess it can be trivial group);
2. any homomorphism $\pi$ of $G$ into a $p$-group is trivial on $N$ i.e. $\pi (N)=1$.

---

**My idea** is to consider the set of all elements whose order cannot divided by $p$, then any element in this set will be sended to the identity by the above $\pi$

Comment: Yes that's right, so you just define $N$ to be the subgroup generated by elements whose order is not divisible by $p$, and show that $N$ has all of the required properties.

Comment: @DerekHolt but how do we know if this forms a subgroup? If $a$ and $b$ both have orders not divisible by $p$ how do we know that $ab$ has an order not divisible by $p$?

Comment: @Math_Day I said "the subgroup generated by the set of these elements". You are right, they do not necessarily form a subgroup.

Comment: ahhhh i see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Not sure this is true.  Consider $A_5$ which is a simple group of order $60$.  Since the only normal subgroups of $A_5$ are $\{e\}$ and $A_5$, and neither of the quotient groups are $p$ groups.

Comment: I guess p-group can be a trivial group.

Comment: In that case $O^p(G)=A_5$ for any prime $p$. (The subgroup $N$ in the question is denoted by $O^p(G)$.)

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that the trivial group was considered a $p$-group.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski I find it hard to imagine why it would not be so considered! Think of the statements that would require qualification, like subgroups and quotient groups of $p$-groups are $p$-groups.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G/N$ is a $p$-group; then if $x\notin N$ and $x^m\in N$ with $m$ minimal we must have that $m$ is a power of $p$, because if $\phi:G\to G/N$ is the surjective homomorphism with kernel $N$ then $\phi(x)\neq e$ and $\phi(x^m)=\phi(x)^m=e$, and $m$ is minimal, meaning $m$ is the order of $\phi(x)$. This criterion is equivalent to $G/N$ being a $p$-group, as it means every element of $G/N$ is a power of $p$.

Suppose $N_1,N_2$ are normal subgroups such that $G/N_1$ and $G/N_2$ are $p$-groups. I claim that $G/(N_1\cap N_2)$ is a $p$-group. To see this, suppose $y\notin N_1\cap N_2$ and let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $y^m\in N_1\cap N_2$. If $y\in N_1-N_2$, then $y\notin N_2$ and $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $y^m\in N_2$, and since $G/N_2$ is a $p$-group this means $m$ is a power of $p$. A similar argument shows $m$ is a power of $p$ if $y\in N_2-N_1$. Suppose then that $y\notin N_1\cup N_2$. Let $r$ be the minimal positive integer such that $y^r\in N_1$ and let $s$ be the minimal positive integer such that $(y^r)^s\in N_2$. Then if $\psi:G\to G/(N_1\cap N_2)$ is the surjective homomorphism with kernel $N_1\cap N_2$ we must have that $\psi(y)^{rs}=e$, so the order of $\psi(y)$ divides $rs$, which is a power of $p$. Since $m$ is minimal and $\psi(y)^m=e$, this implies that $m$ is a power of $p$.

Now we can show that there is a unique minimal normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is a $p$-group by letting $N$ be the intersection of all normal subgroups $N'$ such that $G/N'$ is a $p$-group. By definition, for all $N'$ such that $G/N'$ is a $p$-group we must have that $N\leq N'$. Thus if we have any homomorphism $\phi:G\to P$ with $P$ a $p$-group we must have that $\phi(N)=\{e\}$, so $N$ satisfies the desired conditions. To see that $N$ is unique, let $f:G\to G/N$ be a surjective homomorphism. If $N'$ is such that $G/N'$ is a $p$-group and $N'\neq N$, then there exists an element $z\in N'-N$ and hence $f(z)\neq e$, and we are done.